# SQL: Sums over Combinations

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, sum

Suppose I have a sales table like this:

```
store_id    industry_id    cust_id    amount    gender    age
       1            100       1000       1.00       M      20
       2            100       1000       2.05       M      20
       3            100       1000       3.15       M      20
       4            200       2000       5.00       F      30
       5            200       2000       6.00       F      30
```

Here's the code to generate this table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    store_id int,
    industry_id int,
    cust_id int,
    amount float,
    gender char,
    age int
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,100,1000,1.00, 'M',20);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,100,1000,2.05, 'M',20);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(3,100,1000,3.15, 'M',20);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(4,200,2000,5.00, 'F',30);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(5,200,2000,6.00, 'F',30);
```

Suppose we want to find the sum of amounts spent by each age/gender combination. Something like this:

```
gender    age    total_amount
    M      20            6.20
    F      30           11.00
```

The following code does not work (it throws an "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error):

```
SELECT
    ('M','F') as gender
    , (20,30) as age 
    , (SUM(CASE WHEN gender='M' AND age=20 THEN amount END)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN gender='F' AND age=30 THEN amount END)) as total_amount
FROM t1;
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we want to find the sum of amounts spent by each age/gender combination

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select gender, age, sum(amount) total_amount
from t1
group by gender, age
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6f9454a2daf6118f262d48328b09c4fa)**:

```
gender | age | total_amount
:----- | --: | :-----------
M      |  20 | 6.2         
F      |  30 | 11
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Select gender, age, sum(amount ) as total_amout
from t1
group by gender,age
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT gender
       , age 
       , SUM(amount) as total_amount
FROM t1
where (gender = 'M' and age = 20)
      or (gender = 'F' and age = 30)
group by gender, age
```